# Create view gallery, with page for every image

Tags: views

I have a node "Event Gallery" that has a multiple unlimited image field that I load up to 50 images into for each event.

In manage display, I set the image field as hidden, and instead, I use a views block with a content by ID filter, and the block visibility set to all node type > Event Gallery.

In the past I have used something like colorbox to let users scroll through the gallery, which looks nice, but does not function well when you want visitors to be able to "share" or "like" an individual photo, and for that individual photo to have its own url.

In the image field settings, you can make each image in the gallery link to its file, but I want the file to be shown in the theme, and have its own url.

How do I attach a page to my block view, to show every image of the gallery on its own page, with previous & next links (pager), and for every image to have its own url?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly, something like this should work...

if the url is user defined, create a field using [URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/url). If not, the answer depends on the requirements of the URL.

1 per page: set the pager to limit 1 per page

Link:

- add the link field, set to exclude from display
- add the image field as normal, exclude from display
- create a Global Text, with  tag, using the image field and link field as replacement patterns

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep my original block display, but have the images in that display link to a page of their own. So i need the url to be something like /gallery/event_name/picture_1_name, and then have that as a single item pager, but I need it to be created programatically in the view on node creation. Its a bit like replacing taxonomy pages with views, perhaps i will research that route a bit more.

Comment: ahh, I see. that wasn't entirely clear in the question - so basically you need to determine the position of the image in the view, and use the ?page= url parameter for views, or create your own module for handling the display and paging I would think. If the sort order is the same in the block as in the page, finding that position shouldn't be difficult, then with a pager only allowing one per page you could call the specific page

Comment: Yeah that's right, sorry my question wasn't clear. I've been using views for a couple of years, but cant get my head round this one. I think I need a page display with one paged item to run alongside the node, and somehow have a relation to it. Like node/6/gallery which I think you can do content by ID and use %1 in the path settings.

Comment: an exact method doesn't come to mind, but I will keep thinking about it...